# I want to create html cards with data from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create html cards from a db.
I created num_rows that count how many cards it will make, but when I fetch and then echo it only shows the first row. How do I show all rows?

```
    $cas = 0;
    while($cas < $number){
        $cas++;
        echo "
    <div class='tbook' align='center'>
      <div class='tr'>
       <div class=''>$name</div>
       <div class=''>$role</div>
       <div class=''>$admin</div>
      </div>
    </div>
";
    }
```

Comment: Loop your fetch-method until it returns null. Show more of your code if you want us to tell you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its better idea to use foreach, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
$rows = getDataFromDatabase();
foreach($rows as $row){
  echo "
    <div class='tbook' align='center'>
      <div class='tr'>
       <div class=''>$row['name']</div>
       <div class=''>$row['role']</div>
       <div class=''>$row['admin']</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  "
}
```